# Spring jpa hibernate: read and write data in atomic way

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

I'm using spring 4 with jpa and hibernate and I'm facing the following issue:

I've a table with the following fields:
- ID (PK)
- Provider 
- ProviderId
- Status

this table is used to map a workflow on orders coming from a given provider. Provider and ProviderId should be unique
but I could have different rows for the same (PRovider, ProviderId) in error statuses while I must have in any moment
a maximum of one row for a given Provider,ProviderId in status OPEN. For example, the following is a right configuration:

```
1,PROV,001,CANCELLED
2,PROV,001,ERROR
3,PROV,001,OPEN
```

While this one is not valid:

```
1,PROV1,002,CANCELLED
2,PROV1,002,OPEN
3,PROV1,002,OPEN
```

I've a service class with an addORder method that checks if for the given Provider,OrderID already exists a row in status
OPEN before performing the save. How can I be sure that the check (performing a select) and the db write are performed atomically?? Should the @Transactional annotation work for me? I could add a trigger. Is any smoother way?
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Along with `@Transactional` you need some sort of a Row locking mechanism to guarantee that your Transactions are not conflicted.

If you are using hibernate can use Optimistic locking with `@Version` annotation which is ideal for Read Often Write Less scenarios.

If your writes are more than read then you have to use a Pesimistic locking mechanism.

Please read this post for [more](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html) information

Comment: Thanks @shazin, I'm not sure about the lock. I've no rows to lock. Consider the following scenario. Two concurrent adds are performed for a given provider and providerId, supposing I've two threads doing this activity:
`- T1 check for rows in OPEN status for the given request, none is found
- T2 performs the same check, no rows is found
- T1 writes the new row for the given input in status OPEN
- T2 writes the same row`
in this scenario is difficult to apply a row locking if I'm adding a row that doesn't exist. Am I wrong?

Comment: Any updates on this issue? I've got the same thoughts, wondering if this issue might even be impossible by default with spring jpa